# Rasterize vector layer

Tags: qgis

I am attempting to convert a vector file into a raster file, but unfortunately it is not working, and was wondering what the reason might be?[image]

Comment: Compare the pixel size 30 by 30 and the extent defined for the output. The whole output would fit inside one pixel.

Comment: Better post this as an answer @user30184

Comment: I am rather sure that the question is a duplicate but I haven't done a search yet.